# Finding the number of codes such that all the digits are adjacent. - ZIO 2014 P3

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, recursion

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as8FV.png)

Hello Community!

Can anybody help me with the problem I am posting above as an image link? This is ZIO 2014 P3.

I have tried this problem and the real difficulty of it seems to be that instead of just finding the number of valid codes, you have been constrained with the number of digits. So there are $3$ choices for the second digit, the first digit being $2$ but once we actually go there, we realize that numbers $1$ and $3$ have just two choices but $5$ has only one choice. It may be manageable to do to some extent but actually with $8$ digits and later on, $10$ and $13$ may provide to be a difficult task.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Multiple part problems are discouraged in so far as one might seek merely a sequence of answers without insight.  A better approach would be to pick one part of that problem and restate it in your own terms.  The image provides little context, such as the  book or other resource where you found the problem, and it is a good idea to tell Readers why the problem is important to you.

Comment: Hello hardmath! I want help to solve this problem before because I am preparing for an exam and this is one of the types of questions that are frequently asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT ONLY (since this looks like homework / contest problem)

One way to solve this is to set up a recurrence where $f(a,n) =$ number of codes starting with $a$ and of total length $n$.  Can you write $f(a,n)$ in terms of other $f()$ values of smaller $n$?

(Further optimization: instead of $a=1,2,\dots,9$ you can reduce the space by symmetry.)

Comment: Hello antkam! Thank you for the hint. This is, in fact, a contest problem. Can you please help me with the full solution as I think I have tried this problem enough now and I have already tried doing the recursive method before and could not really find anything. Thanks! :)

Comment: Which contest?  If it is a _past_ contest :) then maybe I can give you the solution.  But really, just try writing $f(1,n)$ in terms of $f(a,n-1)$.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem from Zonal Informatics Olympiad 2014. Link here: https://www.codechef.com/ioi/zio#

Comment: (1) You should always give the **source** of the problem (preferrably link also). 
 If it is a past contest, people are more willing to help.  (2) $f(1,n)$ counts the codes of length $n$ which starts with $1$.  If it starts with $1$, what are the possible next digits?  $f(a,n-1)$ counts the codes of length $n-1$ which starts with $a$.  Can you write $f(1,n)$ in terms of $f(a,n-1)$ now?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try the problem now.

Comment: A lot of people are posting ZIO Problems and one of my friends Vasu090 is too. He posted some problems I saw that I also needed help with. Unfortunately, I don't know any way of reviving threads on MSE. Can you help? Thanks.